# Transform two numbers until they equal each other

Tags: math, collatz

Given two different positive integers, `a` and `b`, can they ever equal each other given the following rules for transforming them (written in python-esque pseudocode):

```
if a < b:
  a = 2a
  b = b-a
elif a > b:
  b = 2b
  a = a-b
else: 
  return True
```

Example of a pair that will equal:

```
11,21
22,10
12,20
24,8
16,16
```

And an example of a pair that will never equal each other:

```
1,4
2,3
4,1
3,2
1,4
repeating...
```

So my question is, can you tell that two numbers will equal without running through a function 
similar to the one above and looking for equality or an infinite loop? Is there any way to tell just by looking at the two numbers?

It kind of reminds me of the Collatz conjecture but with two numbers instead of one.

Having graphed all combinations of two numbers (`a` on the y-axis and `b` on the x-axis) we get a repeating pattern. The yellow indicating pairs that will equal each other. The lower triangle is missing because it's a mirror of the upper triangle. This *was* computed with a modification of the above function. But it would be great not to have to do this because it quickly becomes intractable.

[image]

Comment: I think this is more of a mathematics question than a programming one. But I also think you have enough data to make (and prove) a conjecture ...

Comment: Yes, it is probably more suitable there, what is best practice? Should I remove this question? I think I'm circling the airport, something to do with Mersenne primes...

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest moving it to https://math.stackexchange.com. Note that the question can be easily recast in terms of multiplication by 2 modulo `m = a + b`.

Comment: And a hint: you'll end up with an equal pair if and only if `a` is a multiple of the odd part of `a + b`, or if you want a Python one-liner, if and only if `((a + b) & -(a + b)) * a % (a + b) == 0`.